# Infinite Loop While Running Query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

When I run this query from the command line, it continuously loops. I'm not sure why this is occurring. Could anyone explain this to me, and please offer a fix.

I will be using a query similar to this in a Python script and need to ensure I get the expected data.

```
SELECT `leads`.`status`, `leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c`
FROM leads, leads_cstm
WHERE ((`leads`.`status` = 'Converted') 
  AND  (`leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' 
                                             AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00'))
OR    ((`leads`.`status` = 'AppointmentScheduled') 
  AND  (`leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' 
                                             AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00'));
```

I'm using MySQL, version 5.1.69

Table structure for leads:

```
 leads | CREATE TABLE `leads` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `tbl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `assigned_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salutation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `do_not_call` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `phone_home` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_mobile` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_work` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_other` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_fax` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_address_street` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_address_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_address_state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_address_postalcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary_address_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_address_street` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_address_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_address_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_address_postalcode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alt_address_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assistant` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assistant_phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `converted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `refered_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_source` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_source_description` text,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_description` text,
  `reports_to_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_description` text,
  `contact_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opportunity_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opportunity_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opportunity_amount` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `portal_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `portal_app` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_lead_acct_name_first` (`account_name`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_lead_last_first` (`last_name`,`first_name`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_lead_del_stat` (`last_name`,`status`,`deleted`,`first_name`),
  KEY `idx_lead_opp_del` (`opportunity_id`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_leads_acct_del` (`account_id`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_del_user` (`deleted`,`assigned_user_id`),
  KEY `idx_lead_assigned` (`assigned_user_id`),
  KEY `idx_lead_contact` (`contact_id`),
  KEY `idx_reports_to` (`reports_to_id`),
  KEY `idx_lead_phone_work` (`phone_work`),
  KEY `idx_leads_id_del` (`id`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

leads_cstm is as follows:

```
| leads_cstm | CREATE TABLE `leads_cstm` (
  `id_c` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `buinessdescription_c` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `businessstatus_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numberofemployees_c` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numberofyearsinbusiness_c` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `felonyorbankruptcy_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `encouragedbyagency_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `annualrevenue_c` decimal(26,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productsservices_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `investmoney_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `fivestar_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `socioeconomicstatus_c` text,
  `visamastercard_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `sixreferences_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `investigatedgsa_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `faxedinfopack_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `apptdateourtime_c` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `apptdatetheirtime_c` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `apptstatus_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `topic_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondaryphone_c` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension_c` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezome_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cleadsource_c` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeissuedatebegan_c` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `timingissuelength_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oldsmarteam_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manual_enter_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `suggestedcloser_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lead_type_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'gsalead',
  `qualifier_c` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondarycontact_c` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `siccode_c` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pamcoqualifiermain_c` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `typeofsource_c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_printed_c` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_c`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: Can you post the table structure of both tables?  At this point you are using a CROSS JOIN between the two tables which will generate a Cartesian result, you are not joining on a particular column, is this the intended behavior?  Do you have a column that you can join the two tables on?

Comment: It's unlikely this is "looping", but it could be hanging up

Comment: @JNK I've run it, and I know there are only about 100 that should be returned between that date and time. It runs until I Control+C to interrupt it.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm not sure what you mean by the table structure. I can tell you that status is varchar(100). The only column they both share is the id column.

Comment: @novafluxx that doesn't mean there's a loop, it's probably as bluefeet says you are not using a join key and are creating a cartesian product.

Comment: To get table structure, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE leads;` and add the output in the question. Same for the other table.

Comment: @bluefeet I've edited the post with the leads table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the two tables together or you'll get a combination of the two that's equal to size of leads * size of leads_cstm.

It looks like table leads has an id field that appears to tie to id_c in the leads_cstm table. This is similar to how Goldmine worked too. Ugh.

Try this:

```
SELECT `leads`.`status`, `leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c`
FROM leads, leads_cstm
WHERE
  leads.id = leads_cstm.id_c 
AND 
 (((`leads`.`status` = 'Converted') 
  AND  (`leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' 
                                             AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00'))
OR    ((`leads`.`status` = 'AppointmentScheduled') 
  AND  (`leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' 
                                             AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00')));
```

That's one way to do it... Not the best, though. The better way to be explicit in your join:

```
SELECT `leads`.`status`, `leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c`
FROM leads inner join leads_cstm
    ON leads.id = leads_cstm.id_c
WHERE
 ((`leads`.`status` = 'Converted') 
  AND  (`leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' 
                                             AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00'))
OR    ((`leads`.`status` = 'AppointmentScheduled') 
  AND  (`leads_cstm`.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' 
                                             AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your table structure, I believe part of your problem is you are not currently joining the tables on a particular column.  Your current query is generating a [Cartesian result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) which means that if `leads` has 17 rows and `leads_cstm` has 10 rows the result could be up to 170 rows because each row in the first table will match to each row in the second table.

I am guessing that is not the intended behavior of the query.  Based on your comment that the tables share an `id` column, it seems like you should be able to use something similar to the following:

```
SELECT l.`status`, lc.`apptdateourtime_c`
FROM leads l
INNER JOIN leads_cstm lc
  on l.id = lc.id
WHERE 
(
  l.`status` = 'Converted'
  AND  lc.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00'
)
OR    
(
  l.`status` = 'AppointmentScheduled' 
  AND  lc.`apptdateourtime_c` BETWEEN '2013-06-04 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-05 00:00:00'
);
```

You will notice that I removed the `leads`,`leads_ctsm` and replaced it with an `INNER JOIN`  on the `id` column.  By using the `id` column to join the two tables, you will return only the `ids` that appear in both tables that match the filter in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Currently we use SugarCRM to export this data into CSV. I'm trying to find the query it runs so I can write a script to do it directly. It looks like I'm going to have to do some studying so I fully grasp this.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the stucture of leads. I tried running this and it returned: Unknown column 'lc.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @novafluxx You will use the column in the `leads_ctsm` table that is referencing the `leads` table.  How do you assign the `leads_ctsm` rows to the matching row in the `leads` table?

Comment: Thanks for the help bluefeet, you got me on the right track.